# How to store array in javascript with single quotes ? Is it possible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m trying to create an Query via javascript for filtering products. SELECT * FROM TBN will be in next page. the rest of query i m generating using javascript jquery

Working Fiddle  :http://jsfiddle.net/fo9cct34/

it will create query as per checkbox tick

```
    AND brand=Property 1 OR brand=Property 2 OR brand=Property 3
    AND price > Color 1 OR price > Color 2
    AND camera = Location 1 OR camera = Location 2
```

but now i need to addsingle quaote '  ' quotes like this

```
AND brand='Property 1' OR brand='Property 2' OR brand='Property 3'
AND price > 'Color 1' OR price > 'Color 2'
AND camera = 'Location 1' OR camera = 'Location 2'
```

please someone help me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this in your code: `"'" + this.value + "'"`

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate it with single quote like this

```
if (this.checked) byBrand.push("'"+$(this).attr("value")+"'")
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to put single quotes before and after their values:

```
 $("input").on( "change", function() {
        var str = "";
        if (byBrand.length) str += "    AND brand='" +  byBrand.join(" OR brand='") + "'\n";
        if (byPrice.length) str += (str == "\n" ? "    ":"    AND price > '") + "" +  byPrice.join(" OR price > '") + "'\n";
        if (byCamera.length) str += (str == " \n" ? "    ":"    AND camera") + " ='" +  byCamera.join(" OR camera ='") + "'\n";

        $("#result").html(str);

    });
```

**[See the Updated Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fo9cct34/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

There are more solution.

1. add qoutes when you join the arrays:

`(str == "\n" ? "    ":"    AND price > '") + "" +  byPrice.join('\' OR price > \'') + "'\n";`

2. store the values with qoutes:

`byCamera.push("'" + $(this).attr("value") + "'");`

`removeA(byCamera, "'" + $(this).attr("value") + "'");`

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$("input[name=brand]").on( "change", function() {
    var v = $(this).attr("value");
    var v = '\''+v+'\''
    if (this.checked) byBrand.push(v);
    else removeA(byBrand, v);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Products = [];
    $().ready(function () {
        Products.push({ ProductID: '1', ProductName: 'ABC', ProductCategory: 'XYZ' });
        Products.push({ ProductID: '2', ProductName: 'DEF', ProductCategory: 'XYZ' });
        Products.push({ ProductID: '3', ProductName: 'GHI', ProductCategory: 'XYZ' });

        alert('Product #: ' + Products[2].ProductID + '\n' + 'Product Name: ' + Products[2].ProductName + '\n' + 'Product Category: ' + Products[2].ProductCategory)
    });
```

It will help you